# Recovering a lost file in Solaris 5.10

Tags: solaris, deleted-files

I accidentally removed a file in Solaris Version 5.10 using `rm`.

Can I recover this file in some way or another?

Comment: If you have taken any snapshots/backups then you can, else I am afraid it's gone.

Comment: There are some professional software(some expensive, some not) that can go through lots of complicated processes to retrieve you file, but conventionally: *Your File is Gone*! You can alias `rm` to `rm -i`... But in my opinion you just get used to typing *yes* at the prompt... This will always happen sooner or later, so my advice is: *make backups!* This helps A LOT! If it was a file that comes with Solaris, then you can look up a copy online.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention which filesystem type.  If it's `ufs` rather than `zfs`, the [UFS Explorer](http://www.ufsexplorer.com/und_fmt.php#unix) product may be able to restore the file.